switching xfce workspaces confuses applications
Some applications initiated with an icon take a few seconds to perhaps half a minute to bring up their screen.  During that time, if a different workspace is selected, the initiated application may appear in the new workspace or just not come up.  What should happen if the workspace is switched between the time an application is initiated and the appearance of it's screen (user interface)?
Mozilla thunderbird and firefox finish are coming up in the new workspace.  I had tor and Calibre be confused thus the initiation did not complete until I went back looking for it in the previous workspace and even then it took some time for them to come up.
